# What's the standard way to add custom .on() and .off() operations to custom events in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's possible what I'm describing is ill-advised with more standard approaches, and if so that would be a valid answer.

Say one is creating their own custom event, but in order for it to work the on() and off() steps need to perform actions on the element.

In my example scenario I want to create a custom jquery event called 'multiclick' that fires when an element is clicked 1, 2, or 3 times within a 500 ms timespan.

My initial idea would be to extend the functionality of on, off, and trigger and add my own event like so:

```
(function($)
{
    var oldOn = $.fn.on;
    var oldOff = $.fn.off;
    var oldTrigger = $.fn.trigger;

    // events [, selector ] [, data ], handler
    // events [, selector ] [, data ]
    // Note: this does not implement selector or data for multiclick
    $.fn.on = function(events, handler)
    {
        if (events.split(/\s+/).some(function(event) { return event == 'multiclick'; }))
        {
            $(this).each(function()
            {
                if (!Array.isArray($(this).data('multiclick-state')))
                {
                    $(this).data('multiclick-state', []);
                }
                var clicks = 0;
                var clicksTimer = null;
                var clickHandler = function(e)
                {
                    clicks++;
                    if (clicks == 1)
                    {
                        clicksTimer = setTimeout(function()
                        {
                            handler(e, clicks);
                            clicks = 0;
                        }, 500);
                    }
                    else if (clicks == 3)
                    {
                        clearTimeout(clicksTimer);
                        handler(e, clicks);
                        clicks = 0;
                    }
                };
                $(this).data('multiclick-state').push(
                {
                    handler: handler,
                    clickHandler: clickHandler
                });
                $(this).click(clickHandler);
            });
            arguments[0] = arguments[0].replace('multiclick', '');
        }
        return oldOn.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    // events [, selector ] [, handler ]
    // events [, selector ]
    // events
    // Note: this does not implement selector
    $.fn.off = function(events, handler)
    {
        if (events.split(/\s+/).some(function(event) { return event == 'multiclick'; }))
        {
            $(this).each(function()
            {
                if (!Array.isArray($(this).data('multiclick-state')))
                {
                    $(this).data('multiclick-state', []);
                }
                $(this).data('multiclick-state', $(this).data('multiclick-state').filter(function(state)
                {
                    if (handler == undefined || state.handler === handler)
                    {
                        $(this).off('click', state.clickHandler);
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }.bind(this)));
            });
            arguments[0] = arguments[0].replace('multiclick', '');
        }
        return oldOff.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    // eventType [, extraParameters ]
    // event, [, extraParameters ]
    // Note: I wrote this in case trigger is changed to handle multiple events. Currently it does not. Also I don't support the second overloaded signature
    $.fn.trigger = function(events)
    {
        if (typeof events == 'string' && events.split(/\s+/).some(function(event) { return event == 'multiclick'; }))
        {
            $(this).each(function()
            {
                if (!Array.isArray($(this).data('multiclick-state')))
                {
                    $(this).data('multiclick-state', []);
                }
                // This doesn't support disabling bubbling or stopPropogation, would have to think about it. Very ad-hoc.
                $(this).data('multiclick-state').forEach(function(data)
                {
                    data.clickHandler();
                });
            });
            arguments[0] = arguments[0].replace('multiclick', '');
        }
        return oldTrigger.apply(this, arguments);
    };

    $.fn.multiclick = function(callback)
    {
        if (arguments.length == 1)
        {
            return $(this).on('multiclick', callback);
        }
        else
        {
            return $(this).trigger('multiclick');
        }
        return this;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

I'm not really guaranteeing this is the most complete solution, but it shows the basic approach. Then it would be used like a normal jquery event:

```
function multiclick(e, clicks)
{
    console.log(clicks);
}

// $(document).on('multiclick', multiclick);
$(document).multiclick(multiclick);
//$(document).off('multiclick');
//$(document).off('multiclick', multiclick);
```

jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/rhsswfho/1/

This all just seems like a lot of code for something that should be fairly straightforward or even built into jquery with helper functions, yet I find none. Not to mention it's somewhat fragile and adds a performance penalty to all on, off, and trigger calls.

What would be the standard approach to doing this, or the more standard approach for handling such a problem?

Comment: Really not clear what higher level problem you are trying to solve. This just sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @charlietfl I was trying to create a localized solution. Essentially instead of binding to the document which turns out to be much simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/f35u0fw2

Comment: Still missing a proper problem description. You haven't identified  where you are stuck other than some rambling text and a whole bunch of code and no specific reference to what is or isn't working as expected. See [ask]

Comment: @charlietfl, I was stuck on finding the proper way to tackle creating custom on/off operations. Turns out jquery really doesn't support that approach, and someone in a comment below suggested an alternative approach. I think that's why the question comes off as hard to follow since I was asking for a way to do something that jquery doesn't support. That's one of the reasons I pre-pended my question asking if it was ill-advised. Turns out it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery isn't designed around adding custom operations to on/off events since it's only implementing the DOM events. (Meaning there's no extra code being ran on a per event type basis). Rather than creating a localized solution on the elements this can be accomplished simply by creating a document or body listener like so:

```
var clicks = 0;
var lastTarget = null;
var clicksTimer = null;
$('body').click(function(e)
{
    if (e.target !== lastTarget)
  {
    clearTimeout(clicksTimer);
    lastTarget = e.target;
    clicks = 0;
  }
    clicks++;
  if (clicks == 1)
  {
    clicksTimer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(e.target).trigger('multiclick', clicks);
      clicks = 0;
      lastTarget = null;
    }, 500);
  }
  else if (clicks == 3)
  {
    $(e.target).trigger('multiclick', clicks);
    clearTimeout(clicksTimer);
    clicks = 0;
    lastTarget = null;
  }
});
```

Then used like normal:

```
$('div').on('multiclick', function(e, clicks)
{
    console.log(clicks);
});

$('span').on('multiclick', function(e, clicks)
{
    console.log(clicks);
});
```

Example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f35u0fw2/

What's happening for this specific case is the user can click anywhere and then for elements that are listening they'll get the 'multiclick' event after 1, 2, or 3 clicks as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite straightforward, like you said. You can use the .on() for any kind of event listening. So you could do something like:

```
$('body').on('takeMeToDinner', function() {
    alert('who will pay the bills?');
});
```

and then trigger that event via

```
$('body').trigger('takeMeToDinner');
```

Comment: This doesn't perform custom on/off operations like I requested though.

Comment: @Sirisian why do you think you need "custom on/off events"? Just use a plain event handler and keep track of state in a closure or something.

Comment: @Sirisian, you can perform any actions you wish on any element. You can trigger the event on any element you wish, then, if needed, access that specific element via $(this). So, obviously, the code above isn't the entire function you have to write for your specific use case, but that's how you'd go about handling custom events.

Comment: @Pointy I tried that initially but it doesn't create a reusable event (without code duplication) that can be chained. My example should make that clear. If you try to implement it using your way you'll see the problem. (Imagine this is for a webapp and this multiclick feature is being used in many places).

Comment: @Sirisian, you could create a global document listener with callback function that handles anything you like, initiate it on document ready and trigger that event via any element you wish. The only code duplication will be triggering the event (which you would've had to duplicate anyway) and even that can be mitigated to a certain extent by triggering the event when some sort of logic is met, again, handled by a global function that can be reused. That's pretty reusable, I'd say.

Comment: @l.varga While not localized, that is surprisingly compact. https://jsfiddle.net/f35u0fw2/ I might post that as a solution if no one else posts a simpler answer.

Comment: @Sirisian, that seems like an ok solution to what you're trying to achieve. The only thing I'd change is your events listener for the 'multiclick' event. If you're always listening for clicks on all divs and all spans, then make it so:
$('div, span').on('multiclick', function(e, clicks)
{
 console.log(clicks);
});
It makes it more compact that way.

If you're listening for clicks on particular elements, I'd instead add classes to those elements (eg 'js_multiclick-listener') and listen for multiclicks on those elements.
If my answer helped you in your solution, please mark it as helpful